# Multiple inheritance with different argument size

Tags: python, class, object

I would like to know if this is possible... Currently, I only have a single inheritance... And it's working fine...

In my CiscoPlatform class, I do not have a **init** method so it's expecting 6 arguments when I create the object (as I'm using the BasePlatform **init** method)...

I create the object like this and it works fine:

```
ntw_device = []
device = CiscoPlatform(list[0],list[1],list[2],list[3],list[4],list[5])
ntw_device.append(device)

class BasePlatform(object):
     def __init__(self,ip,hostname,username,password,vendor,type):
         self.ip = ip
         self.hostname = hostname
         self.username = username
         self.password = password
         self.vendor = vendor
         self.type = type

class Cisco(BasePlatform,Interface):
     pass
```

I would like to introduce a new base class called Interface

```
class Interface(object):
     def __init__(self,host,interface,vlan):
         self.host = host
         self.interface = interface
         self.vlan = vlan
```

How would I be able to inherit both parent classes with different number of arguments? Something like this?
*assuming switchport = [] - list of objects

```
class CiscoPlatform(BasePlatform,Interface):
     def __init__(self):
          BaseClass.__init__(self,ntw_device[0].ip,ntw_device[1].hostname,ntw_device[2].username,ntw_device[3].password,ntw_device[4].vendor,ntw_device[5].type)
          Interface.__init__(self,switchport[0].Add to dictionary[1].interface,switchport[2].vlan)
```

How would I still be able to create my objects in that fashion again as CiscoPlatform no longer accepts 6 arguments??

```
device = CiscoPlatform(list[0],list[1],list[2],list[3],list[4],list[5])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you purpose is to ensure `CiscoPlatform` class can accept different numbers of arguments, If that's the case, It won't be hard.
When you initialize the new subclass, its `__init__()` will get called to initiate `CiscoPlatform`. So you just need to check the number of the arguments passed in before you decide which base classes' `__init__` should be used.

`class CiscoPlatform(BasePlatform,Interface):
    def __init__(self, *arg):
        if len(arg) == 6:
            ip,hostname,username,password,vendor,type = arg

            BaseClass.__init__(self,ip,hostname,username,password,vendor,type )
        elif len(arg) == 3:
            host,interface,vlan = arg
            Interface.__init__(self,host,interface,vlan)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Inconsistent arguments number")`